# Java Regex capture first group of slashes

Tags: java, regex

I have the following urls

```
/es-es/Replica-2300/saliffanag/winsrow
/es-de/Bat-00/saliffanag/winsrow
/es-it/Re-2300/saliffanag/winsrow
/es-../
etc..
```

And I need a pattern that captures only /es-es/ or /es-de/ or /es-it/ (the first /...-.../) in Java.

I've tried with this

```
"[^/]*/([^/]*)/"
```

But is not working

How can I achieve this?

Comment: How do you apply that regex? Are you sure the paths always start with a slash? Also please define "it is not working" - do you get too many or too few matches? The regex in general should be ok, you just might need to add `.*` at the end to make it consume the entire input (otherwise you might get multiple matches per path, depending on how you apply it).

Comment: as an advice  in regex start using regex engine before put it into action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a split:

```
"/es-es/Replica-2300/saliffanag/winsrow".split("/", 3)[1]
```

returns "es-es" after that just add the / back on

For variable URLs:

```
String[] split = "padding/test/for/loop/es-es/Replica-2300/saliffanag/winsrow".split("/");
String result = "";  

for(String s : split){
  if(s.length() != 5){ continue;} 
  if(s.charAt(2) == '-'){
    result = s; //if you need the '/' just use result = "/" + s "/";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: But that does not take into account that it has to start with `es-`

Comment: Also , if the URL have more than 3-4 slashes , it wont work . I must capture the first /isocode-isocode/ of a variable url.

Comment: @Saliffanag Updated the answer, maybe that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
\/(es-[a-z]+)\/
```

Try the expression out at [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5KONx9/1).

- `\/` matches the `/` literally - must be escaped
- `()` is the capturing group
- `es-` matches self literally
- `[a-z]+` matches one or more letters together

If the input might be ex. `it-it`, you want to use [`\/(\[a-z\]+-\[a-z\]+)\/`](https://regex101.com/r/9fzkBY/1).

On the other hand, if you have a defined list of the possible suffixes, use [`\/(es-(?:es|de|it))\/`](https://regex101.com/r/rXRqc9/1) where `(?:)` is a non-capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

```
\/([a-z]{2}-[a-z]{2})\/
```

See here: https://regexr.com/4chaj

Regexr will explain in detail how this particular regex is working. Just click on 'Explain'